React Navigation: Adding padding to Stack.Screen elements
I want to add padding between stack.screen elements on the screen so that they are easier to select. Can padding be added somehow? My code sinpet is bellow

        ...
        
        
            
        
        
        
        
        
I tried to use a view element to specify a style but react navigation won't allow a view element withing a  one.
I tried to use a  element to specify a style but react navigation won't allow a view element withing a  one.

react navigation docs doesnt specify all of the things screenOptions can do so I had to use typescript's autocomplete feature to find it; but screenOptions does have a contentStyle option. Use a Stack.Group so that only your desired screens have that styling:
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import HomeScreen from './Home';
import SettingsScreen from './Settings';
import ProfileScreen from './Profile';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Group
          screenOptions={{
            contentStyle: { padding: 10, borderWidth: 3 },
          }}>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={HomeScreen}
            options={{
              title: 'Awesome app',
            }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
        </Stack.Group>
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

Demo
